# How to create a column at psql after join two tables and multiply a quantity by row categories?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've created two tables and inserted values, that's ok:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
  id numeric PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar
);

CREATE TABLE products (
  id numeric PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(50),
  amount numeric,
  price numeric(7,2),
  id_categories numeric REFERENCES categories (id)
);

INSERT INTO categories (id, name)
VALUES 
  (1,   'wood'),
  (2,   'luxury'),
  (3,   'vintage'),
  (4,   'modern'),
  (5,   'super luxury');
  
INSERT INTO products (id, name, amount, price, id_categories)
VALUES 
  (1,   'Two-doors wardrobe', 100,  800,    1),
  (2,   'Dining table', 1000,   560,    3),
  (3,   'Towel holder', 10000,  25.50,  4),
  (4,   'Computer desk',    350,    320.50, 2),
  (5,   'Chair',    3000,   210.64, 4),
  (6,   'Single bed',   750,    460,    1);
```

By now, I have to display a sum based on categories repetition, like this:

I am trying it, but I've been facing errors such as aggregate function not allowed in where:

```
ALTER TABLE
    categories 
ADD COLUMN 
    sum INT;
SELECT 
    categories.name, categories.sum
FROM 
    categories 
JOIN
    products 
        ON categories.id = id_categories
WHERE 
    categories.sum = products.amount *  COUNT(categories.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add group by **categories.name** column to your query.

```
SELECT 
    categories.name, sum(products.amount) AS category_sum
FROM 
    categories 
JOIN
    products 
        ON categories.id = id_categories
GROUP BY
    categories.name
```

Returns:

| name | category_sum |
| --- | --- |
| luxury | 350 |
| modern | 13000 |
| vintage | 1000 |
| wood | 850 |